# 19 digit timestamp conversion in java

Tags: java

Is there any library i can use in java to properly convert 19 digit unix timestamp in the proper human readable date format in java ?

```
Eg:
1547111550416874183
1547111550917748553
```

Comment: Is it just me or do they simply look like the time since the Unix Epoch?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any research?

Comment: @MadProgrammer He used the words 'unix timestamp' in his question

Comment: @Michael But in what precision? Seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds?

Comment: @Michael nanos. Chop off nine digits, `1547111550 = Thu Jan 10 09:12:30 GMT 2019`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah yeah. The converter I pasted into truncated the last 3 digits.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a timestamp in nanoseconds there, by the looks of it. (If it's not in nanos, adjust the `1_000_000_000` accordingly).

Split it into seconds and nanos:

```
long seconds = timestamp / 1_000_000_000;
long nanos = timestamp % 1_000_000_000;
```

Then construct a `java.time.Instant`:

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(seconds, nanos);
```

Then you've got the whole `java.time` API available to do whatever you need to with it.

Comment: Thx . this is what i need

Comment: Please mark question as solved

Answer (score -2):

You can use this :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a");
String date = sdf.format(myTimestamp);
```

Hope it helps !